# cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't return a cell inside if condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to sort my table by date header and have been doing this for days now but my `tableview` doesn't seem to return a `cell`. But if I remove the `if(zrrot < [mEvents count] ) condition` it will return a cell. It's weird.

I cannot put `indexPath.row` in here `[cell setEvent:[mEvents objectAtIndex: ]];` because it will not sort the data according to its the header.

(The app is a voip app)

Here's my code:

```
NSUInteger zzrot = 0;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

RecentsCell *cell = (RecentsCell*)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"RecentsCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecentsCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
}


if([[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqual: finalArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]])
{
    if(zrrot < [mEvents count] ){           
        @synchronized(mEvents){
            [cell setEvent:[mEvents objectAtIndex: zzrot]];
            zrrot++;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

else{
    NSLog(@"Do nothing");
    //do nothing
    return cell;
    } 
 }
```

Here's the setEvent:

```
-(void)setEvent: (NgnHistoryEvent*)event{    

        labelType.text = event.remoteParty;
        labelDisplayName.text = event.remotePartyDisplayName;

        labelDate.text = [[NgnDateTimeUtils chatDate] stringFromDate:
                          [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: event.start]];
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be performing these sorts of comparisons in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You should sort the data in your array so that all `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has to do is access something like `someArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`.  There is no guarantee as to in which order `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called; it could be called for (0,5) then (0,3) then (0,4) and so on, particularly as the table view scrolls.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that there is no guarantee as to in which order it will be called. Where can I read more of those? In Apple Documentation?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of documentation on how tableviews work as well as many tutorials on the web.  The tableview calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as it needs to.   Cells are reused. For example, if your table fits 5 cells then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called for the first 5 rows.  Scroll down and it will be called for the next rows, but the cell returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will be one of the cell objects that scrolled off the screen.  Scroll up again and the method will be called to get the cells for the rows that have now reappeared (rows 0-5).